# How to retain control state of master page with diffrent content pages in asp .net

Tags: asp.net

I have some combobox in master page and some content page, when jump from on content page to other state of combobox changed.

How can i preserve the state of combobox in master page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to save the state somewhere in a database connected to the user cookie.

Comment: Is there any other solution for same

Comment: to save it to a cookie, but you add overhead and you can not save many  on cookie.